# What cpu is this?

Tags: cpu, xeon

I know that is is an Intel Xeon processor based on what is written on the CPU but i cant seem to match what i believe to be the part number to anything on the internet.  The CPU has the following written on it:

```
INTEL '05 5110
INTEL XEON
SLAGE CHINA
1.6GHz/4M/1066
E737A702
```

I have looked on the internet to the best of my ability but couldn't find anything that matched.  Any ideas what CPU this is?  Where can i find the full specifications for it?

Comment: you can use a free program like cpu-z to see system details like the CPU.

Comment: Sadly i do not believe i have a functional motherboard that can use this cpu.

Comment: [I was able to find which CPU it was without much of a problem by doing a Bing search.](https://www.bing.com/search?q=Intel+Xeon+5110)

Comment: And I was able to find it with Google with searching `intel cpu 1.6GHz/4M/1066` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas what CPU this is?

it is a [Intel® Xeon® Processor 5110](http://ark.intel.com/products/27214/Intel-Xeon-Processor-5110-4M-Cache-1_60-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB)

Comment: can you explain how you figured this out so i wont have to ask again.?

Comment: I did a Bing search for  [Intel Xeon 5110](https://www.bing.com/search?q=Intel+Xeon+5110&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN)

Comment: Oh so thats what matters not the E737A702 ok i got it thank you